# copying image from windows clipboard using vba

Tags: excel, vba

How can I copy a image file from windows clipboard to excel sheet using VBA macro?

i know how we can extract strings but what about images?

```
Function FnGetTextFromClipBoard()

    Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim strText

       objData.GetFromClipboard
       strText = objData.GetText()

       MsgBox strText

End Function
```

http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-get-text-from-the-windows-clipboard/

Answer (score 0):

After you copy it to the clipboard all you have to do is the following statement and it should paste there.

```
Cells(10, 6).PasteSpecial
```